# ORA-01858 error update date using to_date

Tags: php, oracle11g

i have a query update like this,

```
Update Member SET NM_MEMBER = '$nm', nonaktif_member = TO_DATE('$tgl_habis', 'MM/DD/YYYY') WHERE ID_MEMBER = '$id';
```

Before query update there is looping for $tgl_habis,

```
$perpanjang = $_POST['perpanjang'];
$i = 0;
while ($i < 12) {
   $i++;
   if ($i == $perpanjang) {
       $tgl_habis = date('mdY', strtotime("+$i month"));
   }
}
```

When i execute that query, show ORA-01858. Is the an error occurs on the conversion date ?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you formatted date as "mdY", but in query you saying it's "MM/DD/YYYY". You have to unite that.

Comment: It could be one more thing. In PHP `d` in date function means `01-31`, but in Oracle `DD` means `1-31`. So try using `j` in PHP instead of `d`. http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

Comment: Thanks, it works :) My mistakes not see the difference. @David